No displayport over USBC with lenovo ideapad gaming 3 (15IHU6)
Displayport over USBC on linux not recognized
I am using archlinux on the Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 15IHU6,
I cannot get a display to react to the usbc port connection.
USBC-USBC is recognized as a "USB billboard device"
USBC-DP(mini) is recognized as a "Displayport Alt mode"
Neither display any image, neither in X or outside. (My previous laptop - a Tuxedo Computers one) displayed console on all screens attached at boot time).

drivers in use:
nvidia_drm            126976  2
nvidia_uvm           6717440  0
nvidia_modeset       1650688  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              72564736  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
video                  81920  4 ideapad_laptop,xe,i915,nvidia_modeset
ideapad_laptop         69632  0
platform_profile       12288  1 ideapad_laptop
rfkill                 40960  5 iwlmvm,bluetooth,ideapad_laptop,cfg80211
sparse_keymap          12288  2 intel_hid,ideapad_laptop
video                  81920  4 ideapad_laptop,xe,i915,nvidia_modeset
i8042                  57344  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    32768  3 video,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop

$ pacman -Ss nvidia | grep -i installed -A1
extra/egl-wayland 4:1.1.16-1 [installed]
    EGLStream-based Wayland external platform
--
extra/libvdpau 1.5-3 [installed]
    Nvidia VDPAU library
extra/libxnvctrl 560.35.03-1 [installed]
    NVIDIA NV-CONTROL X extension
--
extra/nvidia 560.35.03-3 [installed]
    NVIDIA drivers for linux
--
extra/nvidia-settings 560.35.03-1 [installed]
    Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
extra/nvidia-utils 560.35.03-2 [installed]
    NVIDIA drivers utilities
--
extra/vulkan-nouveau 1:24.2.2-1 [installed]
    Open-source Vulkan driver for Nvidia GPUs
extra/xf86-video-nouveau 1.0.17-3 (xorg-drivers) [installed]
    Open Source 3D acceleration driver for nVidia cards


mkinitio.conf:
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect microcode modconf keyboard keymap consolefont block filesystems fsck)
MODULES=(nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm)

devices:
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:400-3ff irq:183 memory:6104000000-6104ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:610-60f irq:184 memory:54000000-54ffffff memory:6000000000-60ffffffff memory:6100000000-6101ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)

X setup:
$ xrandr
[...]
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 196mm
   3840x2160     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98    30.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98* 
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    30.00    25.00    59.94    29.97    24.00    23.98  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "modesetting"
    VendorName     "Intel Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection


Do you have the right USB-C cable for the display, and check the BIOS.

there is nothing in the BIOS about USBC, only displaymode "switchable" or "u..." something i can't recall.
The usbc-usbc is 3.2 gen 1 5A.
The usbc-minidp .. well .. are there different kinds of that, too?

USB-C cables differ in Data transfer, Video and Power. Check bios for Display Port or USB C for display

I believe you can set in the BIOS that a display is available on the USB-C port right when you start the laptop. That's how it works on my Lenovo devices

BIOS has neither USBC nor Display Port settings. I read somewhere that in some cases "advanced" settings are actually locked out and need to be activated by some keypress sequence. maybe try that then.

in my bios unter > config > display > boot display device = USB Type-C

however would it make sense that the os would recognize "displayport alt mode" on the usbc but not be able to use it?

yes, this could make sense the os might recognize the "displayport alt mode" on the usb-c port but still fail to use it, recognition doesn’t mean full functionality is available

check this: drivers are missing or incompatible, bios settings don’t enable it, hw limitations or conflicts or you need a new firmware update

If this is the modell you got IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IHU6
You can't use your usb-c for video output only for data transfer
USB-C 3.2 Gen 1 (data transfer only)
Check this:
 IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IHU6 Overview
What you can try is buy a cheap used docking station, and you should be able to connect additional monitors to it or ask Lenovo service if it's possible.
Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 15IHU6 82K1 Docking Station.
Edit:
Apparently, it will not work with the docking station if you connect it via the USB-C port.
Check the Lenovo forum, you're probably not the only one with this problem.
Does IdeaPad Gaming 3-15IHU6 - Type 82K1 support DP signal from USB-C Port 
External Monitor

Monitor Support
Supports up to 2 independent displays (native display and 1 external monitor via HDMI®)
• HDMI supports up to 3840x2162@60Hz


Indeed, it looks like I am shit out of luck. The confusing part in the spec is where it says it supports two independent displays. I guess I read into that that it was two independent of the display that is attached to the computer.
